# Segmentation fault при разборе аргументов main() c++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, argv

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно определить аргументы командной строки и исходя из полученых команд проделать некие действия. Запуская программу из параметрами разными параметрами я получаю сообщение `Segmentation fault`.
Помогите понять, что я делаю неверно. Зарание извиняюсь за столь ужасный код.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    MySniffer snf;

    if(argc == 1 || argc == 3 || argc > 4) {
        cout << "Wrong options. Read program options.\n" << snf.usage_inf() << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        if(strcmp(argv[i], "select") == 0) {
                cout << "hello" << endl;
            for(int j = i; j < argc; ++j){
                if(strcmp(argv[j], "iface") == 0){
                    string str = string(argv[3]);
                    snf.setIface(str);
                    snf.pkgMonitor(snf.get_cmd());
                }
            }       
        }

        if(strcmp(argv[i], "show") == 0) {
            for(int j = i; j < argc; ++j) {
                if(strcmp(argv[j], " count")){
                    if(snf.select_data(argv[2])==1){
                        cout << "There is no adress " << argv[2] << " or data base wasn't created.\n"
                        << "Check if you select network interface.\n";
                    }
                    snf.pkgMonitor(snf.get_cmd());

                }
            }
        }

        if(strcmp(argv[i], "--help") == 0) {
            for(int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
                cout << argv[i] << endl;
            cout << snf.usage_inf() << endl;
            snf.pkgMonitor(snf.get_cmd());
        }

        if(strcmp(argv[i], "stop") == 0) {
            cout << "Packets are not sniffed.\n" << endl;
            snf.set_cmd(true);
        }

        if(strcmp(argv[i], "start") == 0){
            if(snf.isIfaceDeff()){
                cout << "Packets are being sniffed from now on\n" << endl;
            }

            else {
                cout << "You first need to select your interface. Read program options.\n" << snf.usage_inf() << endl;
            }
            snf.set_cmd(false);
            snf.pkgMonitor(snf.get_cmd());
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Несмотря на корявый код, я думаю, что проблема связана с одной из вызываемых из main функций.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow, нашел ошибку в одной из этих функций. Мне теперь удалить ответ или как лучше сделать?

Comment: Думаю, лучше просто удалить ответ.

Comment: Я имел в виду "удалить вопрос".:)

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow, я тоже, но после нажатия "удалить" появилось сообщение о том, что запретят мне задавать вопросы) страшно)

Comment: Я проголосовал закрыть вопрос. Если еще несколько участников сделают то же самое, то он будет просто закрыт.

Answer (score 1):

У вас могут быть только `argc==2` и `argc==4`, судя по строчке

```
if(argc == 1 || argc == 3 || argc > 4) {
```

Один из вопросов - что будет тут

```
if(strcmp(argv[j], "iface") == 0){
    string str = string(argv[3]);
```

при `argc == 2`?...

То же и с

```
if(snf.select_data(argv[2])==1){
    cout << "There is no adress " << argv[2] << " or data base wasn't created.\n"
```

И, кстати, в

```
if(strcmp(argv[i], "select") == 0) {
    cout << "hello" << endl;
    for(int j = i; j < argc; ++j){
        if(strcmp(argv[j], "iface") == 0){
```

какой смысл сравнивать с `iface` тот аргумент, который заведомо равен `select` - я имею в виду, начинать с `int j = i`?

Comment: предположим, что при `argc == 2` должны вызываться или `stop` или `start`. До `if(strcmp(argv[j], "iface") == 0){
    string str = string(argv[3]);` дойти не должно.

Comment: Тогда надо смотреть с конкретными данными в руках :) "Предположим" - это плохой метод поиска ошибок...

Comment: согласен. но мне на данном этапе лиш бы работало)